# How do you conduct multiple t-tests per stratum in stratified sampling?

Tags: hypothesis-testing

Suppose that I am concerned with the effect of treatment in each stratum, let's say A, B, and C. What is the most appropriate statistical method given that I want to understand the treatment effect and its statistical significance within each group?

I've considered the following methods:

1. Stratified T-Test
2. Stratified Sampling with T-Test per stratum
3. Randomized Complete Block Design

I've read up on articles on how approaches 1 and 3 are utilized, and it seems that they evaluate the effect across the groups as a whole. So, this leaves me to consider evaluating the stratum using a T-Test, separately.

But, if I do so, should I also be concerned with FPR inflation and corrections on either the P-value or significance level to mitigate this?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I'm not familiar with stratified t-tests. Is there a reason you wouldn't just use a linear model/regression/ANOVA/ANCOVA here, and analyse all your data in one model?

Answer (score 0):

I would go for a linear regression (or GLM's, in case of distribution families other than Gaussian). Then, you can use packages like `emmeans` that will allow you to look at the effect per stratum.

Take a look at this vignette for the basics of this package. It has a cool examples on linear regressions and analysis on stratuns:
https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/emmeans/vignettes/basics.html